# How do I best go about removing a chimney shrub?

Tags: roofing

Do you have any top tips in removing a shrub growing out of a chimney? It must be a good 3-4 feet & still growing. It's growing out the side of the stack. Other than have it removed, repoint the brick work, and cap the chimney, is there anything else I can do to ensure it doesn't grow back. I'm hoping it does all come out! Expensive tree planting not of my choice!

Comment: Picture? I'd like to see that!

Answer (score 1):

Wow...you must live where everything grows. Yes, remove the fern and then treat the chimney with a herbicide or cleaning/sterilization solution.

I'd make sure all the roots,etc. are removed. You wouldn't want a chimney fire from old dry roots.

Comment: After cutting the shrub, apply Roundup to any exposed parts you didn't want to dig out or remove and wait a week for the roots to die and dry out.  Then you can get them out easier.

Answer (score 0):

I would use crossbow or a woody plant herbicide roundup is for grass or broad leaf and it will not be effective on a woody plant as crossbow. Cut off the tree, bush but leave some of the base exposed and coat the wood with crossbow especially the fresh cut, then give it time the larger it is the longer it will take to dry out. I have used crossbow on tree stumps that I could not get a grinder or backhoe to to remove the stump, it did take some time but there were no new shoots coming up and the stumps started rotting out much faster than my neighbors (we did them at the same time).

Comment: You might want to link to or define this "crossbow" you mention.  I had visions of trying to shoot it down

Comment: As I wrote a woody plant herbicide that is a description.

Comment: That sentence parses as (crossbow) or (a woody plant herbicide). Had you said "a*nother* woody plant herbicide" it would make more sense.  (A full stop or semicolon between "herbicide" and "roundup" would help too)